# Ajax post/get with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of data that comes through my get ajax query... I display them with append().

Now, when I click on the displayed data, I want to add it to my database (I have an associative entity) through an ajax post query. I need to have the id of the data I clicked

What is the best way to do this? I thought about giving all my div the ID of the data stored in my database then take this ID to do my post but I feel like it is not the good way to go... I feel strange to store ID from database in div.

I have already done all my on click function but the way I must get my ID is blocking me now.

Comment: You effectively have two options - either add the ID, either as an `id` or a `data-*` attribute on the corresponding HTML element (e.g. your `div`) or create some sort of association in memory so that when making the `PUT` request, you can get & set the proper ID. In general it's recommended to not use the DOM as a database, but storing an ID doesn't seem to approach that. Especially since `id` itself is a standard HTML attribute & there may be value in each `div` having a unique `id` anyway.

Comment: If I can avoid to put all IDs in my div, I will be fine... I have something like 4000 divs, but yes I must access to all IDs... I know from what I've seen that it is possible witch React, but what about jQuery? I can't have my IDs hidden

Comment: Why do you feel the need to avoid adding an `id` to each `div` even though it's a standard HTML attribute? And what do you mean by you "can't have my IDs hidden"?

Comment: I don't really know, I'm probably wrong but I was thinking that it was a really bad way to have all IDs from database stored in divs, that's all!